# Extending Error es6 class module issue

Tags: javascript, class, error-handling, babeljs

I'm having a pretty strange bug. I'm trying to debug why I can't get this module [es6-error](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/es6-error) working with babel 6. The tests keep failing. One of these tests is fairly simple an instance of the custom error should be an error. Both of these should be `true`.

```
console.log(err instanceof Error)
console.log(err instanceof ExtendableError)
```

Here's examples of the exact same `src` code on jsbin working where both of the logs return `true`.

- [jsbin with uncompiled working babel code](http://jsbin.com/mozoyamalu/2/edit?js,console)
- [jsbin with compiled working babel code](http://jsbin.com/mozoyamalu/1/edit?js,console)

The same behavior occurs if you put that code into **one** node file and run it.

It's apparent that the reason the tests are failing is because of the module import isn't working properly, this oddly fails.

```
import ExtendableError from './index'

var b = new ExtendableError();

console.log(b instanceof ExtendableError) // false
console.log(b instanceof Error) // true
```

Why is it that when the declaration for `ExtendableError` is in the same file as the `console.log` I get `true`, `true` valid behavior, and when I have `ExtendableError` in it's own file it becomes `false`, `true`?

Here's the [output of the working babel 5 code](https://gist.github.com/reggi/9a1d68ff46dcefa4e9e4bc41af5cbb53#file-old-working-babel-5-js).

Comment: it works for me http://esnextb.in/?gist=8c056fab3c332cc84ede7a00613dc8f2

Comment: @MauricioPoppe That's because you're using the current module using es5.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to stop using Babel's polyfill for `extends` and do the extension on your own

```
class ExtendableError {
  constructor(message = '') {
    Error.call(this, message)

    // extending Error is weird and does not propagate `message`
    Object.defineProperty(this, 'message', {
      enumerable : false,
      value : message,
      writable : true,
    });

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'name', {
      enumerable : false,
      value : this.constructor.name,
      writable : true,
    });

    if (Error.hasOwnProperty('captureStackTrace')) {
      Error.captureStackTrace(self, this.constructor);
      return
    }

    Object.defineProperty(this, 'stack', {
      enumerable : false,
      value : (new Error(message)).stack,
      writable : true,
    });
  }
}

ExtendableError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype)

var b = new ExtendableError()

console.log(b instanceof Error) // true
console.log(b instanceof ExtendableError) // true
```

Comment: Checkout my answer above! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @ThomasReggi Awesome, I was about to write that the error was in calling `Object.getPrototypeOf(ExtendableError).call(this, message)` which is equivalent to call `Error.call(this, message)` which indeed returns an error instance, the transform effectively creates a new layer between `ExtendableError` and `Error` and doing `Layer.call(this, message)` returns undefined instead of an error :)

Answer (score 0):

Headed over the the babel slack channel and was promptly filled in about this plugin that allows this backward compatibility with babel 5.

https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend

```
{
  ["babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend", {
    "globals": ["Error"],
    "approximate": true
  }]
}
```

[Here's the pr to es6-error.](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/es6-error/pull/16/files#diff-b9cfc7f2cdf78a7f4b91a753d10865a2R43)